# ggplot smoothing optimisation for high resolution data

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I'm looking at various smoothing options for some noisy, high resolution data and I'm wondering if ggplot2 `geom_smooth()` can be optimised to give the results I'm after.

The default 'gam' method produces less that adequate results, and the 'loess' method can't handle the amount of data.  Are there better ways to handle this?

```
p <- ggplot(data=fid_df,aes(x=rt,y=value, group=1,text=paste("height = ", value, " RT = ",round(rt,3)))) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_smooth(aes(colour='red')) +
    xlim(10,55) +
    ylim(8, ceiling(max(fid_df$value[fid_df$rt>10])/10)*10)
```

[image: Plot as generated by above code]

A better (but still not ideal) solution for smoothing was obtained using the base plot function and `colMeans`, which captures the shape of the original data and eliminates a little bit of the noise, but not enough:

```
x<-fid_df$rt
y<-fid_df$value
plot(x,y, xlim=c(8,max(x)),ylim=c(8,max(y[x>8])*1.1),type="l")
k <- 20 #the number of rows to average over for smoothing
sig.new <- colMeans(matrix(y, nrow=k))
x.new <- colMeans(matrix(x, nrow=k))
lines(x.new,sig.new, col='lightslateblue')
```

[image: Base plot with colMeans(k=20) overlay]

A close up of the baseline shows the noise reduction achieved by this method:

```
plot(x,y, xlim=c(18,23),ylim=c(8.8,8.95),type="l")
lines(x.new,sig.new, col='red')
```

[image: Baseline close up of base plot]

The ideal result would maintain the shape of actual peaks while eliminating noise especially from the baseline. The end objective is to distinguish the actual peaks from the baseline within a given tolerance in order to measure the area of each peak. Something like this: (generated in different software):

[image: chromatography baseline]

A subset of the data (the full data has almost 72,000 rows):

```
> dput(fid_df[20200:20800,])
structure(list(rt = c(16.832558914251, 16.833392252667, 16.834225591083, 
16.835058929499, 16.8358922679151, 16.8367256063311, 16.8375589447471, 
16.8383922831631, 16.8392256215791, 16.8400589599952, 16.8408922984112, 
16.8417256368272, 16.8425589752432, 16.8433923136592, 16.8442256520752, 
16.8450589904913, 16.8458923289073, 16.8467256673233, 16.8475590057393, 
16.8483923441553, 16.8492256825713, 16.8500590209874, 16.8508923594034, 
16.8517256978194, 16.8525590362354, 16.8533923746514, 16.8542257130674, 
16.8550590514835, 16.8558923898995, 16.8567257283155, 16.8575590667315, 
16.8583924051475, 16.8592257435635, 16.8600590819796, 16.8608924203956, 
16.8617257588116, 16.8625590972276, 16.8633924356436, 16.8642257740596, 
16.8650591124757, 16.8658924508917, 16.8667257893077, 16.8675591277237, 
16.8683924661397, 16.8692258045557, 16.8700591429718, 16.8708924813878, 
16.8717258198038, 16.8725591582198, 16.8733924966358, 16.8742258350518, 
16.8750591734679, 16.8758925118839, 16.8767258502999, 16.8775591887159, 
16.8783925271319, 16.8792258655479, 16.880059203964, 16.88089254238, 
16.881725880796, 16.882559219212, 16.883392557628, 16.884225896044, 
16.8850592344601, 16.8858925728761, 16.8867259112921, 16.8875592497081, 
16.8883925881241, 16.8892259265401, 16.8900592649562, 16.8908926033722, 
16.8917259417882, 16.8925592802042, 16.8933926186202, 16.8942259570363, 
16.8950592954523, 16.8958926338683, 16.8967259722843, 16.8975593107003, 
16.8983926491163, 16.8992259875324, 16.9000593259484, 16.9008926643644, 
16.9017260027804, 16.9025593411964, 16.9033926796124, 16.9042260180285, 
16.9050593564445, 16.9058926948605, 16.9067260332765, 16.9075593716925, 
16.9083927101085, 16.9092260485246, 16.9100593869406, 16.9108927253566, 
16.9117260637726, 16.9125594021886, 16.9133927406046, 16.9142260790207, 
16.9150594174367, 16.9158927558527, 16.9167260942687, 16.9175594326847, 
16.9183927711007, 16.9192261095168, 16.9200594479328, 16.9208927863488, 
16.9217261247648, 16.9225594631808, 16.9233928015968, 16.9242261400129, 
16.9250594784289, 16.9258928168449, 16.9267261552609, 16.9275594936769, 
16.9283928320929, 16.929226170509, 16.930059508925, 16.930892847341, 
16.931726185757, 16.932559524173, 16.933392862589, 16.9342262010051, 
16.9350595394211, 16.9358928778371, 16.9367262162531, 16.9375595546691, 
16.9383928930851, 16.9392262315012, 16.9400595699172, 16.9408929083332, 
16.9417262467492, 16.9425595851652, 16.9433929235812, 16.9442262619973, 
16.9450596004133, 16.9458929388293, 16.9467262772453, 16.9475596156613, 
16.9483929540774, 16.9492262924934, 16.9500596309094, 16.9508929693254, 
16.9517263077414, 16.9525596461574, 16.9533929845735, 16.9542263229895, 
16.9550596614055, 16.9558929998215, 16.9567263382375, 16.9575596766535, 
16.9583930150696, 16.9592263534856, 16.9600596919016, 16.9608930303176, 
16.9617263687336, 16.9625597071496, 16.9633930455657, 16.9642263839817, 
16.9650597223977, 16.9658930608137, 16.9667263992297, 16.9675597376457, 
16.9683930760618, 16.9692264144778, 16.9700597528938, 16.9708930913098, 
16.9717264297258, 16.9725597681418, 16.9733931065579, 16.9742264449739, 
16.9750597833899, 16.9758931218059, 16.9767264602219, 16.9775597986379, 
16.978393137054, 16.97922647547, 16.980059813886, 16.980893152302, 
16.981726490718, 16.982559829134, 16.9833931675501, 16.9842265059661, 
16.9850598443821, 16.9858931827981, 16.9867265212141, 16.9875598596301, 
16.9883931980462, 16.9892265364622, 16.9900598748782, 16.9908932132942, 
16.9917265517102, 16.9925598901262, 16.9933932285423, 16.9942265669583, 
16.9950599053743, 16.9958932437903, 16.9967265822063, 16.9975599206224, 
16.9983932590384, 16.9992265974544, 17.0000599358704, 17.0008932742864, 
17.0017266127024, 17.0025599511185, 17.0033932895345, 17.0042266279505, 
17.0050599663665, 17.0058933047825, 17.0067266431985, 17.0075599816146, 
17.0083933200306, 17.0092266584466, 17.0100599968626, 17.0108933352786, 
17.0117266736946, 17.0125600121107, 17.0133933505267, 17.0142266889427, 
17.0150600273587, 17.0158933657747, 17.0167267041907, 17.0175600426068, 
17.0183933810228, 17.0192267194388, 17.0200600578548, 17.0208933962708, 
17.0217267346868, 17.0225600731029, 17.0233934115189, 17.0242267499349, 
17.0250600883509, 17.0258934267669, 17.0267267651829, 17.027560103599, 
17.028393442015, 17.029226780431, 17.030060118847, 17.030893457263, 
17.031726795679, 17.0325601340951, 17.0333934725111, 17.0342268109271, 
17.0350601493431, 17.0358934877591, 17.0367268261751, 17.0375601645912, 
17.0383935030072, 17.0392268414232, 17.0400601798392, 17.0408935182552, 
17.0417268566712, 17.0425601950873, 17.0433935335033, 17.0442268719193, 
17.0450602103353, 17.0458935487513, 17.0467268871673, 17.0475602255834, 
17.0483935639994, 17.0492269024154, 17.0500602408314, 17.0508935792474, 
17.0517269176635, 17.0525602560795, 17.0533935944955, 17.0542269329115, 
17.0550602713275, 17.0558936097435, 17.0567269481596, 17.0575602865756, 
17.0583936249916, 17.0592269634076, 17.0600603018236, 17.0608936402396, 
17.0617269786557, 17.0625603170717, 17.0633936554877, 17.0642269939037, 
17.0650603323197, 17.0658936707357, 17.0667270091518, 17.0675603475678, 
17.0683936859838, 17.0692270243998, 17.0700603628158, 17.0708937012318, 
17.0717270396479, 17.0725603780639, 17.0733937164799, 17.0742270548959, 
17.0750603933119, 17.0758937317279, 17.076727070144, 17.07756040856, 
17.078393746976, 17.079227085392, 17.080060423808, 17.080893762224, 
17.0817271006401, 17.0825604390561, 17.0833937774721, 17.0842271158881, 
17.0850604543041, 17.0858937927201, 17.0867271311362, 17.0875604695522, 
17.0883938079682, 17.0892271463842, 17.0900604848002, 17.0908938232162, 
17.0917271616323, 17.0925605000483, 17.0933938384643, 17.0942271768803, 
17.0950605152963, 17.0958938537123, 17.0967271921284, 17.0975605305444, 
17.0983938689604, 17.0992272073764, 17.1000605457924, 17.1008938842084, 
17.1017272226245, 17.1025605610405, 17.1033938994565, 17.1042272378725, 
17.1050605762885, 17.1058939147046, 17.1067272531206, 17.1075605915366, 
17.1083939299526, 17.1092272683686, 17.1100606067846, 17.1108939452007, 
17.1117272836167, 17.1125606220327, 17.1133939604487, 17.1142272988647, 
17.1150606372807, 17.1158939756968, 17.1167273141128, 17.1175606525288, 
17.1183939909448, 17.1192273293608, 17.1200606677768, 17.1208940061929, 
17.1217273446089, 17.1225606830249, 17.1233940214409, 17.1242273598569, 
17.1250606982729, 17.125894036689, 17.126727375105, 17.127560713521, 
17.128394051937, 17.129227390353, 17.130060728769, 17.1308940671851, 
17.1317274056011, 17.1325607440171, 17.1333940824331, 17.1342274208491, 
17.1350607592651, 17.1358940976812, 17.1367274360972, 17.1375607745132, 
17.1383941129292, 17.1392274513452, 17.1400607897612, 17.1408941281773, 
17.1417274665933, 17.1425608050093, 17.1433941434253, 17.1442274818413, 
17.1450608202573, 17.1458941586734, 17.1467274970894, 17.1475608355054, 
17.1483941739214, 17.1492275123374, 17.1500608507534, 17.1508941891695, 
17.1517275275855, 17.1525608660015, 17.1533942044175, 17.1542275428335, 
17.1550608812496, 17.1558942196656, 17.1567275580816, 17.1575608964976, 
17.1583942349136, 17.1592275733296, 17.1600609117457, 17.1608942501617, 
17.1617275885777, 17.1625609269937, 17.1633942654097, 17.1642276038257, 
17.1650609422418, 17.1658942806578, 17.1667276190738, 17.1675609574898, 
17.1683942959058, 17.1692276343218, 17.1700609727379, 17.1708943111539, 
17.1717276495699, 17.1725609879859, 17.1733943264019, 17.1742276648179, 
17.175061003234, 17.17589434165, 17.176727680066, 17.177561018482, 
17.178394356898, 17.179227695314, 17.1800610337301, 17.1808943721461, 
17.1817277105621, 17.1825610489781, 17.1833943873941, 17.1842277258101, 
17.1850610642262, 17.1858944026422, 17.1867277410582, 17.1875610794742, 
17.1883944178902, 17.1892277563062, 17.1900610947223, 17.1908944331383, 
17.1917277715543, 17.1925611099703, 17.1933944483863, 17.1942277868023, 
17.1950611252184, 17.1958944636344, 17.1967278020504, 17.1975611404664, 
17.1983944788824, 17.1992278172984, 17.2000611557145, 17.2008944941305, 
17.2017278325465, 17.2025611709625, 17.2033945093785, 17.2042278477945, 
17.2050611862106, 17.2058945246266, 17.2067278630426, 17.2075612014586, 
17.2083945398746, 17.2092278782907, 17.2100612167067, 17.2108945551227, 
17.2117278935387, 17.2125612319547, 17.2133945703707, 17.2142279087868, 
17.2150612472028, 17.2158945856188, 17.2167279240348, 17.2175612624508, 
17.2183946008668, 17.2192279392829, 17.2200612776989, 17.2208946161149, 
17.2217279545309, 17.2225612929469, 17.2233946313629, 17.224227969779, 
17.225061308195, 17.225894646611, 17.226727985027, 17.227561323443, 
17.228394661859, 17.2292280002751, 17.2300613386911, 17.2308946771071, 
17.2317280155231, 17.2325613539391, 17.2333946923551, 17.2342280307712, 
17.2350613691872, 17.2358947076032, 17.2367280460192, 17.2375613844352, 
17.2383947228512, 17.2392280612673, 17.2400613996833, 17.2408947380993, 
17.2417280765153, 17.2425614149313, 17.2433947533473, 17.2442280917634, 
17.2450614301794, 17.2458947685954, 17.2467281070114, 17.2475614454274, 
17.2483947838434, 17.2492281222595, 17.2500614606755, 17.2508947990915, 
17.2517281375075, 17.2525614759235, 17.2533948143395, 17.2542281527556, 
17.2550614911716, 17.2558948295876, 17.2567281680036, 17.2575615064196, 
17.2583948448356, 17.2592281832517, 17.2600615216677, 17.2608948600837, 
17.2617281984997, 17.2625615369157, 17.2633948753318, 17.2642282137478, 
17.2650615521638, 17.2658948905798, 17.2667282289958, 17.2675615674118, 
17.2683949058279, 17.2692282442439, 17.2700615826599, 17.2708949210759, 
17.2717282594919, 17.2725615979079, 17.273394936324, 17.27422827474, 
17.275061613156, 17.275894951572, 17.276728289988, 17.277561628404, 
17.2783949668201, 17.2792283052361, 17.2800616436521, 17.2808949820681, 
17.2817283204841, 17.2825616589001, 17.2833949973162, 17.2842283357322, 
17.2850616741482, 17.2858950125642, 17.2867283509802, 17.2875616893962, 
17.2883950278123, 17.2892283662283, 17.2900617046443, 17.2908950430603, 
17.2917283814763, 17.2925617198923, 17.2933950583084, 17.2942283967244, 
17.2950617351404, 17.2958950735564, 17.2967284119724, 17.2975617503884, 
17.2983950888045, 17.2992284272205, 17.3000617656365, 17.3008951040525, 
17.3017284424685, 17.3025617808845, 17.3033951193006, 17.3042284577166, 
17.3050617961326, 17.3058951345486, 17.3067284729646, 17.3075618113806, 
17.3083951497967, 17.3092284882127, 17.3100618266287, 17.3108951650447, 
17.3117285034607, 17.3125618418768, 17.3133951802928, 17.3142285187088, 
17.3150618571248, 17.3158951955408, 17.3167285339568, 17.3175618723729, 
17.3183952107889, 17.3192285492049, 17.3200618876209, 17.3208952260369, 
17.3217285644529, 17.322561902869, 17.323395241285, 17.324228579701, 
17.325061918117, 17.325895256533, 17.326728594949, 17.3275619333651, 
17.3283952717811, 17.3292286101971, 17.3300619486131, 17.3308952870291, 
17.3317286254451, 17.3325619638612), value = c(8.83893229166667, 
8.84375, 8.844921875, 8.84544270833333, 8.84544270833333, 8.84518229166667, 
8.84466145833333, 8.84231770833333, 8.83984375, 8.83854166666667, 
8.83645833333333, 8.83489583333333, 8.83359375, 8.83958333333333, 
8.84088541666667, 8.84205729166667, 8.8375, 8.83802083333333, 
8.83815104166667, 8.838671875, 8.83802083333333, 8.840234375, 
8.83958333333333, 8.84088541666667, 8.83880208333333, 8.83984375, 
8.83958333333333, 8.8421875, 8.84622395833333, 8.849609375, 8.84856770833333, 
8.84596354166667, 8.84114583333333, 8.83841145833333, 8.83645833333333, 
8.83697916666667, 8.83984375, 8.84479166666667, 8.84791666666667, 
8.847265625, 8.84244791666667, 8.84192708333333, 8.84231770833333, 
8.84140625, 8.840234375, 8.83776041666667, 8.839453125, 8.83958333333333, 
8.84010416666667, 8.843359375, 8.84557291666667, 8.84661458333333, 
8.843359375, 8.84192708333333, 8.84205729166667, 8.8421875, 8.84114583333333, 
8.83958333333333, 8.83958333333333, 8.84140625, 8.83997395833333, 
8.83841145833333, 8.83841145833333, 8.840234375, 8.84088541666667, 
8.83932291666667, 8.84192708333333, 8.843359375, 8.84609375, 
8.84635416666667, 8.84921875, 8.84596354166667, 8.842578125, 
8.83684895833333, 8.83697916666667, 8.84309895833333, 8.84635416666667, 
8.84830729166667, 8.84427083333333, 8.84505208333333, 8.84557291666667, 
8.84791666666667, 8.85104166666667, 8.85247395833333, 8.85078125, 
8.84596354166667, 8.84205729166667, 8.84114583333333, 8.84140625, 
8.84049479166667, 8.83997395833333, 8.84036458333333, 8.84231770833333, 
8.84440104166667, 8.84934895833333, 8.84934895833333, 8.84557291666667, 
8.838671875, 8.83854166666667, 8.83828125, 8.83606770833333, 
8.83515625, 8.83854166666667, 8.83997395833333, 8.83958333333333, 
8.83828125, 8.841796875, 8.84283854166667, 8.842578125, 8.84453125, 
8.84401041666667, 8.84466145833333, 8.83841145833333, 8.838671875, 
8.84322916666667, 8.84661458333333, 8.85065104166667, 8.84947916666667, 
8.84830729166667, 8.84518229166667, 8.84231770833333, 8.844140625, 
8.84375, 8.84361979166667, 8.84322916666667, 8.841015625, 8.840234375, 
8.83984375, 8.84127604166667, 8.84309895833333, 8.84322916666667, 
8.84557291666667, 8.84622395833333, 8.84544270833333, 8.84348958333333, 
8.84075520833333, 8.84270833333333, 8.8484375, 8.85221354166667, 
8.84973958333333, 8.84361979166667, 8.839453125, 8.841015625, 
8.84153645833333, 8.84296875, 8.84283854166667, 8.84544270833333, 
8.84635416666667, 8.84609375, 8.84479166666667, 8.84440104166667, 
8.84453125, 8.846875, 8.84921875, 8.85104166666667, 8.85013020833333, 
8.84674479166667, 8.84674479166667, 8.84609375, 8.84466145833333, 
8.84375, 8.84375, 8.84713541666667, 8.845703125, 8.84739583333333, 
8.84778645833333, 8.84973958333333, 8.84700520833333, 8.84479166666667, 
8.84700520833333, 8.84830729166667, 8.85104166666667, 8.850390625, 
8.8484375, 8.84947916666667, 8.85247395833333, 8.85442708333333, 
8.85403645833333, 8.85221354166667, 8.85390625, 8.851953125, 
8.851171875, 8.85013020833333, 8.855078125, 8.86002604166667, 
8.86588541666667, 8.86471354166667, 8.86432291666667, 8.86341145833333, 
8.86184895833333, 8.859765625, 8.85807291666667, 8.85872395833333, 
8.85625, 8.855078125, 8.85677083333333, 8.86041666666667, 8.8625, 
8.86015625, 8.85885416666667, 8.86015625, 8.86263020833333, 8.86653645833333, 
8.86341145833333, 8.85911458333333, 8.854296875, 8.85885416666667, 
8.86458333333333, 8.86653645833333, 8.86809895833333, 8.87122395833333, 
8.87473958333333, 8.87434895833333, 8.87200520833333, 8.870703125, 
8.86796875, 8.86640625, 8.86549479166667, 8.86666666666667, 8.86640625, 
8.86796875, 8.86692708333333, 8.86549479166667, 8.8609375, 8.86158854166667, 
8.86328125, 8.86458333333333, 8.864453125, 8.86458333333333, 
8.86627604166667, 8.862890625, 8.862890625, 8.86432291666667, 
8.86341145833333, 8.86145833333333, 8.85950520833333, 8.8625, 
8.864453125, 8.86263020833333, 8.86184895833333, 8.86106770833333, 
8.86341145833333, 8.86471354166667, 8.86575520833333, 8.86692708333333, 
8.86458333333333, 8.86080729166667, 8.85572916666667, 8.858203125, 
8.85716145833333, 8.85533854166667, 8.854296875, 8.86041666666667, 
8.87005208333333, 8.86875, 8.86223958333333, 8.856640625, 8.859765625, 
8.86119791666667, 8.85572916666667, 8.8515625, 8.84895833333333, 
8.8484375, 8.84856770833333, 8.85182291666667, 8.85299479166667, 
8.84908854166667, 8.84635416666667, 8.84765625, 8.84986979166667, 
8.84739583333333, 8.84947916666667, 8.85403645833333, 8.86158854166667, 
8.86197916666667, 8.86028645833333, 8.8578125, 8.85794270833333, 
8.858984375, 8.85872395833333, 8.85911458333333, 8.85638020833333, 
8.85299479166667, 8.85234375, 8.85416666666667, 8.86041666666667, 
8.85859375, 8.85546875, 8.85143229166667, 8.85026041666667, 8.849609375, 
8.84700520833333, 8.84765625, 8.84609375, 8.84765625, 8.848046875, 
8.85104166666667, 8.85598958333333, 8.85755208333333, 8.8578125, 
8.85338541666667, 8.85026041666667, 8.85052083333333, 8.85234375, 
8.85286458333333, 8.85403645833333, 8.85533854166667, 8.85729166666667, 
8.85338541666667, 8.85013020833333, 8.84869791666667, 8.85013020833333, 
8.8515625, 8.85169270833333, 8.846875, 8.840234375, 8.83854166666667, 
8.84166666666667, 8.84895833333333, 8.85286458333333, 8.85481770833333, 
8.848828125, 8.84518229166667, 8.84427083333333, 8.85013020833333, 
8.85247395833333, 8.85390625, 8.8515625, 8.84830729166667, 8.84869791666667, 
8.85013020833333, 8.85247395833333, 8.84791666666667, 8.84205729166667, 
8.84036458333333, 8.84322916666667, 8.84505208333333, 8.84270833333333, 
8.841796875, 8.84401041666667, 8.84713541666667, 8.84778645833333, 
8.84583333333333, 8.84244791666667, 8.83997395833333, 8.83841145833333, 
8.84153645833333, 8.84296875, 8.84388020833333, 8.83997395833333, 
8.83580729166667, 8.83333333333333, 8.83971354166667, 8.84283854166667, 
8.844140625, 8.836328125, 8.834765625, 8.834375, 8.840234375, 
8.842578125, 8.84609375, 8.84674479166667, 8.848046875, 8.84908854166667, 
8.84674479166667, 8.841015625, 8.836328125, 8.836328125, 8.83645833333333, 
8.83697916666667, 8.83815104166667, 8.84166666666667, 8.84153645833333, 
8.84114583333333, 8.84479166666667, 8.84700520833333, 8.84791666666667, 
8.84270833333333, 8.84309895833333, 8.84427083333333, 8.84388020833333, 
8.84166666666667, 8.833984375, 8.83385416666667, 8.83177083333333, 
8.83268229166667, 8.83684895833333, 8.83932291666667, 8.84205729166667, 
8.84088541666667, 8.837890625, 8.84010416666667, 8.84231770833333, 
8.84778645833333, 8.84674479166667, 8.84192708333333, 8.84127604166667, 
8.84153645833333, 8.844140625, 8.84322916666667, 8.83932291666667, 
8.83723958333333, 8.83893229166667, 8.84557291666667, 8.84700520833333, 
8.84440104166667, 8.84166666666667, 8.84088541666667, 8.83958333333333, 
8.84153645833333, 8.84375, 8.85182291666667, 8.851953125, 8.85364583333333, 
8.85104166666667, 8.84908854166667, 8.8453125, 8.841015625, 8.84036458333333, 
8.84440104166667, 8.85078125, 8.859765625, 8.86158854166667, 
8.86041666666667, 8.858203125, 8.86067708333333, 8.86614583333333, 
8.86901041666667, 8.873828125, 8.87643229166667, 8.87408854166667, 
8.87278645833333, 8.87578125, 8.88515625, 8.88919270833333, 8.89075520833333, 
8.89557291666667, 8.90286458333333, 8.91380208333333, 8.92317708333333, 
8.93138020833333, 8.93697916666667, 8.94244791666667, 8.949609375, 
8.958203125, 8.96875, 8.98372395833333, 8.996484375, 9.01041666666667, 
9.02018229166667, 9.035546875, 9.050390625, 9.06979166666667, 
9.08658854166667, 9.10846354166667, 9.1265625, 9.151171875, 9.17057291666667, 
9.192578125, 9.21510416666667, 9.24231770833333, 9.27278645833333, 
9.30104166666667, 9.32760416666667, 9.35286458333333, 9.3796875, 
9.40989583333333, 9.43567708333333, 9.46341145833333, 9.494140625, 
9.53125, 9.56692708333333, 9.60377604166667, 9.644921875, 9.67994791666667, 
9.7109375, 9.74205729166667, 9.77825520833333, 9.81471354166667, 
9.848046875, 9.88515625, 9.92161458333333, 9.95572916666667, 
9.98723958333333, 10.0186197916667, 10.0555989583333, 10.090625, 
10.1231770833333, 10.150390625, 10.173828125, 10.1985677083333, 
10.22265625, 10.2481770833333, 10.2680989583333, 10.285546875, 
10.2967447916667, 10.306640625, 10.3169270833333, 10.3319010416667, 
10.34375, 10.349609375, 10.351171875, 10.3553385416667, 10.3583333333333, 
10.3572916666667, 10.3537760416667, 10.3514322916667, 10.3506510416667, 
10.3477864583333, 10.33515625, 10.3174479166667, 10.2983072916667, 
10.28515625, 10.2708333333333, 10.249609375, 10.2208333333333, 
10.1932291666667, 10.1661458333333, 10.1401041666667, 10.117578125, 
10.094921875, 10.0670572916667, 10.0345052083333, 10.0061197916667, 
9.985546875, 9.95768229166667, 9.921875, 9.88645833333333, 9.85559895833333, 
9.83177083333333, 9.80338541666667, 9.77330729166667, 9.73580729166667, 
9.70208333333333, 9.66744791666667, 9.64166666666667, 9.61614583333333, 
9.58684895833333, 9.55455729166667, 9.525390625, 9.49947916666667, 
9.47174479166667, 9.43411458333333, 9.40260416666667, 9.373828125, 
9.34778645833333, 9.32447916666667, 9.29739583333333, 9.27760416666667, 
9.255078125, 9.23567708333333, 9.21302083333333, 9.18854166666667, 
9.16692708333333, 9.14921875, 9.13294270833333, 9.11666666666667, 
9.09973958333333, 9.08606770833333, 9.07213541666667, 9.05794270833333, 
9.04466145833333, 9.03203125, 9.017578125, 9.00234375, 8.990234375, 
8.985546875, 8.97890625, 8.96979166666667, 8.96041666666667, 
8.95247395833333, 8.94388020833333, 8.93684895833333, 8.93059895833333, 
8.92161458333333, 8.90807291666667, 8.90221354166667, 8.90546875, 
8.90520833333333, 8.89674479166667, 8.887109375, 8.88411458333333, 
8.88567708333333, 8.88333333333333, 8.8796875, 8.8734375, 8.870703125, 
8.87005208333333, 8.86966145833333, 8.87057291666667, 8.87109375, 
8.8703125, 8.86471354166667, 8.85963541666667, 8.86236979166667, 
8.86236979166667, 8.86171875, 8.854296875, 8.85338541666667, 
8.85234375, 8.850390625)), row.names = 20200:20800, class = "data.frame")
```

#### Edit: Attempted use of regSmooth package

Here I have applied the github.com/domwoolf/regSmooth package to a small section of data shown in close up on the baseline. The red line is the smoothed values, the black line is the original data, and the vertical dotted blue and green lines are local minima and maxima respectively, as detected using the turning point function from the 'pastecs' package.  Notice that the smoothed line has large dips before and after the major peak at ~12.4 on the x axis.  These aren't present in the raw data and they lead to misplaced local minima when calculated using the smoothed line.  Also, in the more or less flat region between x=12.05 and x=12.15, several minima and maxima are identified, indicating insufficient smoothing in that region. The smoothing was accomplished using the regSmoothAuto function, which automates optimization of the lambda value.  Perhaps a manual assignment of lambda would improve the smoothing achieved here?

```
plot(x,y, type = 'l',ylim=c(floor(min(y)), ceiling(mean(tail(fid_df)$value))))  
regsmoothed_fid<-regSmoothAuto(x,y)  
lines (regsmoothed_fid$yhat ~ x, col="red", lw=2)

tp<-pastecs::turnpoints(y)
abline(v=x[tp$peaks],lty=2, col='blue')
  abline(v=x[tp$pits],lty=2,col='green')
```

[image: regSmooth smoothing with minima and maxima]

#### Edit: pracma::whittaker()

The `pracma::whittaker()` smoothing function applied to a 1 minute subset of my data produces similar artifacts to those mentioned above for the `regSmoothAuto()` function. i.e large dips before and after major peaks.

[image: pracma::whittaker smoothing result]

Comment: Are you open to using a rolling window function?

Comment: @M.Viking yes, I'm open to experimenting with as many options as possible

Comment: Can you re-post your data in a way that is easier to import. like `dput(fid_df[23700:23900,])`

Comment: I added the dput output on a slightly different window to capture more baseline.  See edit above.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ac034173t) (A Perfect Smoother; Paul H. C. Eilers) describes an algorithm extremely well suited to your needs.  I have written an R package with it that you can get using

```
devtools::install_github('domwoolf/regSmooth')
```

Using this on your example data

```
fid$yhat = regSmooth(fid$rt, fid$value, 3e-5, d = 3)$yhat
```

we get [image]

zooming on on the baseline, it looks like this

```
fid.plot = fid[fid$rt<17.1, ]
plot(fid.plot$rt, fid.plot$value, col='blue', type='l')
lines(fid.plot$rt, fid.plot$yhat, col='red')
```

[image]

---

**Update**
Since your x values are uniformly spaced, a simpler version of this algorithm can also be used.  This simpler version (which assumes uniformly monotonically incremented x values) is available in the package pracma.  In this version, the default value of lambda provides reasonable smoothing.

```
library(pracma)
fid$yhat = whittaker(fid$value)
```

gives us

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've spent a couple of hours playing around with this.  The article is interesting, but I have to confess that the math is mostly beyond me.  Consequently, I'm not really sure what the lambda value is doing.  I tried the function from your package which automates optimisation of lambda (regSmoothAuto()), but it was too computationally demanding for my data set (it crashed the virtual box I'm running R in 3 times).  On a smaller subset of data it generated some artifacts which I'll include an image of as an edit to my question above.  Please take a look there and advise further.  Thanks.

Comment: from `?regSmooth` "lambda: smoothing parameter (positive real numeric). **Higher values give greater smoothing. Smaller values follow data more closely.**"  You could try increasing the value to get more smoothing.  Try increasing in multiples of 10 first. Once you find a value in the right ballpark, try smaller changes to fine tune.  Hope it helps. I've found this algorithm very effective over the years for many hard-to-smooth data.

Comment: I spent a bit of time getting parameter s that work on your example data. results added to answer

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do that, @dww.  It looks quite nice on that small sub-section of data.  Exactly what I am looking for actually.  However, the algorithm doesn't seem to live up to Eilers' (2003) claims for computational efficiency.  The lamba optimisation function takes a very long time to calculate even somewhat larger data sets (I tried it on a 12 minute section and had to give up after an hour and a half).  Moreover, the optimal lambda value isn't consistent between different data sets or sections of a single data set.

Comment: My aim is to use this process to apply to many different samples with different peak shapes and sizes, so I'm not sure if selecting an arbitrary value for lambda will give satisfactory results across different samples.  I will experiment a little to find out if this is true, but it seems obvious that calculating optimal lambda on each sample is unrealistic.

Comment: Since your x values are uniform, a simpler function works with defaults.  I added that to the answer.  <Although I'm not quite sure why I put so much effort into helping someone that does not bother to give an upvote... > BTW your comment about optimising the lambda coefficient being slow is a mis-reading of Eilers.  It is the smoothing algorithm that is very efficient, not so much the cross validation.

Comment: Thanks again @dww.  Rest assured that your efforts to help me are greatly appreciated. Upvotes will be forthcoming.

Comment: The pracma::whittaker function seems to introduce similar artifacts to those produced by regsmoothAuto.  I'll edit my question with a picture of the result of whittaker() applied to a larger stretch of data.  But basically large sharp peaks in the raw data seem to produce preceding and trailing dips in the smoothed values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using the RcppRoll rolling mean function, to get the mean of every 5 records in a sliding window.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppRoll/index.html

```
#install.packages("RcppRoll")
library(RcppRoll)
df$value2 <- roll_mean(df$value, n=5, fill=0)
```

Example

```
df<-data.frame(row=1:1000, value=sample(c(1:100), 1000, replace=T))
df$value2<-roll_mean(df$value, n=10, fill=0)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=row)) + geom_line(aes(y=value), color="blue", alpha=0.5)+geom_line(aes(y=value2), color="red")
```

[image]

Comment: This result is very similar to the colMeans approach I tried above.  Some version of this approach will probably get me to where I want eventually (best result so far is colMeans on 30 columns, and then applying the result of that to another colMeans on every second column... which may be the same as just calling colMeans on 60 columns..?)  But I'd still like to know if ggplot2 can do this type of smoothing natively.